# HTML Code formatting on VISUAL STUDIO CODE on a MAC is not working

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I cannot get HTML code formatting to work on Visual Studio code on a Mac.

It is working for JavaScript and CSS, but not for HTML.

I have the "Prettier" code formatter installed.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You aren't [ignoring](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html) HTML files with Prettier are you?

Comment: How can you check?

Comment: You should have a line like this in .prettierignore `
*.html`

Comment: I don't have a .pretteirignore file. I set the setting for Prettier to format on Save.  It works with my .CSS file.  It has no effect on my .HTML file.  It does not format it.